# How to manually decrypt an ASP.NET Core Authentication cookie?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's consider a common-known ASP.NET Core scenario. Firstly we add the middleware:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookie",
        CookieName = "MyCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login/"),
        AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied/"),
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    });
    //...
}
```

Then serialize a principal:

```cs
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookie", principal);
```

After these two calls an encrypted cookie will be stored at the client side. You can see the cookie (in my case it was chunked) in any browser devtools:

[image: chunked encrypted cookie generated by ASP.NET]

It's not a problem (and not a question) to work with cookies from application code.

My question is: **how to decrypt the cookie outside the application**? I guess a private key is needed for that, how to get it?

I checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) and found only common words:

> This will create an encrypted cookie and add it to the current
> response. The AuthenticationScheme specified during configuration must
> also be used when calling SignInAsync.
>
> Under the covers the encryption used is ASP.NET's Data Protection
> system. If you are hosting on multiple machines, load balancing or
> using a web farm then you will need to configure data protection to
> use the same key ring and application identifier.

So, is it possible to decrypt the authentication cookie, and if so how?

**UPDATE #1:**
Based on Ron C [great answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842511/how-to-manually-decrypt-an-asp-net-core-authentication-cookie/42857830#42857830), I've ended up with code:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    //constructor is omitted...
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(
            new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookie",
            CookieName = "MyCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookie", new ClaimsPrincipal());

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult DecryptCookie()
    {
        var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));

        string cookieValue = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];

        var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(
            typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).FullName, "MyCookie", "v2");

        UTF8Encoding specialUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
        byte[] protectedBytes = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue);
        byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
        string plainText = specialUtf8Encoding.GetString(plainBytes);

        return Content(plainText);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this code always produces exception on `Unprotect` method call:

> CryptographicException in Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll:
> Additional information: The payload was invalid.

I tested different variations of this code on several machines without positive result. Probably I made a mistake, but where?

**UPDATE #2:** My mistake was the `DataProtectionProvider` hasn't been set in `UseCookieAuthentication`. Thanks to @RonC again.

Comment: could you update your answer with correct code?

Comment: The accepted answer has been given by @RonC, not me. His code is correct.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

### Decrypting the Authentication Cookie without needing the keys

It's worth noting that you don't need to gain access to the keys to decrypt the authentication cookie.  You simply need to use the right `IDataProtector` created with the right purpose parameter, and subpurpose parameters.

Based on the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` source code https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L4 it looks like the purpose you need to pass is `typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware)`. And since they are passing additional parameters to the `IDataProtector` you will need to match them.  So this line of code should get you an `IDataProtector` that can be used to decrypt the authentication cookie:

```cs
var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).FullName, Options.AuthenticationScheme, "v2");
```

Note that `provider` here is an `IDataProtectionProvider` obtained from the DI container and `Options.AuthenticationScheme` is just "MyCookie" in this case since that's what it was set to in the `Configure` method of the startup.cs file.

Here is an example action method for decrypting your authentication cookie two different ways:

```cs
public IActionResult DecryptCookie() {

    //Get the encrypted cookie value
    string cookieValue = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];

    //Get a data protector to use with either approach
    var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).FullName, "MyCookie", "v2");


    //Get the decrypted cookie as plain text
    UTF8Encoding specialUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);
    byte[] protectedBytes = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue);
    byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
    string plainText = specialUtf8Encoding.GetString(plainBytes);


    //Get the decrypted cookie as a Authentication Ticket
    TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue);

    return View();
}
```

This method uses an `IDataProtectionProvider` called `provider` that is constructor injected.

### Decrypting the Authentication Cookie when persisting keys to a directory

If you want to share cookies between applications then you might decide to persist the data protection keys to a directory.  This can be done by adding the following to the `ConfigureServices` method of the startup.cs file:

```cs
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(
        new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));
```

**BE CAREFUL** though because the keys are not encrypted so it's up to you to protect them!!!  Only persist the keys to a directory if you absolutely must, (or if you are just trying to understand how the system works).  You will *also* need to specify a cookie `DataProtectionProvider` that uses those keys.  This can be done with the help of the `UseCookieAuthentication` configuration in the `Configure` method of the startup.cs class like so:

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
        DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\")),
        AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookie",
        CookieName = "MyCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
        AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied"),
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    });
```

With that configuration done.  You can now decrypt the authentication cookie with the following code:

```cs
 public IActionResult DecryptCookie() {
        ViewData["Message"] = "This is the decrypt page";
        var user = HttpContext.User;        //User will be set to the ClaimsPrincipal

        //Get the encrypted cookie value
        string cookieValue = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
        

        var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));

        //Get a data protector to use with either approach
        var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).FullName, "MyCookie", "v2");


        //Get the decrypted cookie as plain text
        UTF8Encoding specialUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);
        byte[] protectedBytes = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue);
        byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
        string plainText = specialUtf8Encoding.GetString(plainBytes);


        //Get teh decrypted cookies as a Authentication Ticket
        TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue);

        return View();
    }
```

You can learn more about this latter scenario here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing

Comment: Thanks! I successfully got the key. However, the cookie's value is not a valid Base64 string because it contains invalid characters like `_` or `-`. Direct `protector.Unprotect` call also isn't working with that string. Have you any idea how to format the cookie's value? Like `CfDJ8Id0LxnC1ZdOqPkWYYQ7uRQKZub1FQoPnSDNwhgiuuJXOUXQYAEMUuYj886KD5vjOFdFEubf_eLlJQU4IZSsO6DNds_FSFCj3wqUTZZEF9BmHMnT40BOrVo03YBH7QGG_XG4EhHl20445H94ywhwGIAefKOhEPqd0m-xpyPFuKwkpPxuMXFl8HKhpI_uoMJJvEalFMOvxfJylTl2kMfmcBW2tgY5J9jjkDgIz-SFUpxZgPcogjTG3hunW-fpgCdLMlGCUKSKTZEYF-hkNCcswGI`

Comment: Looks like the converted the + and / chars to - and _ but not necessarily in that order.  I'll see if I can find the code where the did that.

Comment: You need to call Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue) to get the encrypted bytes.

Comment: Call `protector.Unprotect(Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue));` throws `CryptographicException in Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll: Additional information: The payload was invalid.` I tried to recreate key and to call `Unprotect` within the same process which created the cookie but without success.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide full code.  I tested the code before posting it.  It might make sense for you to ask a separate questions about "How to gain access to Asp.Net Core encryption keys" and I can move that part of my answer to that question.  That would make the info more available to others rather than having two questions in this one question. Can you do that?

Comment: Really nice post about something I had been questioning but hadn't needed to deep dive.

Comment: @RonC I've posted the question. Feel free to edit it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913017/how-to-gain-access-to-asp-net-core-encryption-keys.

Comment: I still can't get this solution to work. There is `The payload was invalid` message all the time. Do you call `services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(someDir)` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`? Give me some time, I'll check the code under different environment.

Comment: You don't need to persist the keys to a file to get the above action method to decrypt the authentication cookie.  (Although doing so shouldn't prevent it from working) I've never used stack overflow chat before but I'd be happy to try if you want more interactive help. It's important to note that what you call the `AuthenticationScheme` in your `CookieAuthenticationOptions` in the startup.cs class MUST MATCH what you pass in the CreateProtector method.  In this case that is 'MyCookieMiddlewareInstance'.  If they are different, that's one way to get the error you are seeing.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov remember to accept the answers if they answer your questions.

Comment: I tried again and still can't solve the puzzle. Could you look at my original question for a moment? I've added a code example.

Comment: Updated my answer to provide details of how to decrypt the authentication cookie if the keys are being persisted to a directory.  The important bit is that the cookie DataProtectionProvider must be specified in the startup.cs `Configure` method.

Comment: Hurrah! Setting of  `DataProtectionProvider` in `UseCookieAuthentication` resolved the issue. Thank you a thousand times.

Comment: Looks like in Core 2.0 the CookieAuthenticationMiddleware class has been replaced, but the string value of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware" is still used. https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/a7bf561b1c76aaee3d68c7448d780bc925ee283e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L38

Comment: I am still having issues with this working with .NET core 2.0 and a chunked cookie. Any ideas? I'm concatenating the cookie values together and using the cookie name in the DataProtectionProvider. Thanks.

Comment: In case you specified an application name when adding the data protection service  `services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\")).SetApplicationName("MyApplicationName");` be sure to specify the same name in the `DataProtectionProvider.Create` call:  `var dataProtection = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"),
                cfg => cfg.SetApplicationName("MyApplicationName"));`

Comment: For any case: default authentication scheme is `Identity.Application` (in the example above it's renamed to `MyCookie`). So, the creation of protector must looks like `dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware","Identity.Application", "v2")` to avoid `The payload was invalid.` exception. I spend a lot of time trying to find default value and decrypt my cookies.

Comment: @MaximDobryakov is your comment in response to James H comment?  I believe the code in my answer ultimately uses (through variables) the hard coded values you mention.

Comment: Can any of this be leveraged for a cookie generated in ASP.NET MVC 4 and to be "decrypted" in .NET Core?  Use case: authentication in ASP MVC, and .net core functions needing to validate the cookie.

Comment: @AaronHudon possibly, but probably not.  It would depend on whether the dot net core libraries for such functionality were callable from MVC 4.  But probably not.  For cross framework sharing of cookie you’d probably be better off looking into encryption from a library like BouncyCastle that can be used from MVC 4 and asp.net Core.

Comment: @RonC thanks for reply.  I could be reading this incorrectly, but this page may indicate it is possible? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps

Comment: @AaronHudon Agreed.  It looks like it's a use case they designed in.  I wasn't aware of that.  Glad to have your link here to those docs as it may help others in the future.

Comment: I had to remove `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true` for this to work.

Comment: Can you please update your first code snippet to show how you declare/initialize `provider`?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner  I added "Note that `provider` here is an `IDataProtectionProvider` obtained from the DI container." Hopefully that's enough to unblock you.

Answer (score 26):

While inside ASP.NET Core app you can just use `CookieAuthenticationOptions.TicketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue)`.

Here, a simple static method I wrote:

```cs
public static AuthenticationTicket DecryptAuthCookie(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    // ONE - grab the CookieAuthenticationOptions instance
    var opt = httpContext.RequestServices
        .GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions>>()
        .Get(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); //or use .Get("Cookies")

    // TWO - Get the encrypted cookie value
    var cookie = opt.CookieManager.GetRequestCookie(httpContext, opt.Cookie.Name);

    // THREE - decrypt it
    return opt.TicketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookie);
}
```

Works fine under .NET 5 and .NET 6 and further.

I'm adding this answer for reference, because this question pops up on every search engine if you search for how to manually decrypt ASP.NET auth cookie.

### Update from 2024:

Sorry, I came back with some notes.

While the above code works perfectly fine, keep in mind, that decrypting is always a CPU-intensive operation (as with anything crypto-related).

Basically you are decrypting the data twice - 1st time the ASP.NET Core does it for you, then you do it *again*, manually. If you have a high-load app that serves thousands or requests every minute, this can have a big impact on performance.

Instead of manually decrypting a cookie, why not extract the data from what you already have (i.e. the `HttpContext`)

For example:

```cs
//let's get the decrypted ticket properties from context-features
var authResult = httpContext.Features.Get<IAuthenticateResultFeature>()?.AuthenticateResult;
//Good. Now let's read some data from it

//for example let's read the auth cookie issue date
var issueDate = authResult.Properties.IssuedUtc;
```

P.S. Jeep in mind that `IAuthenticateResultFeature` can be `null` if the requests comes from anonymous user. Also keep in mind that `AuthenticateResult` can also be `null` if you're overwriting the `HttpContext.User` in your code (for example you have a custom priciple class with some custom logic). I spent hours debugging this. In that case - move the code up the pipe in the middleware, right after `UseAuthentication()` call.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core Identity, had to use .Get("Identity.Application") instead of .Get(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Comment: This worked up to step two for me. After step three I had NULL, which I didn't expect. I'm open to ideas.

Comment: @DonRolling did you call `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` and `app.UseAuuthentication` in your Startup.cs?

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit I'm pretty sure that I figured it out, but I made a job change since then, so I can't look at the code and see what fixed it. Thanks for following up though!

Comment: Hello again guys. Can someone help me. I made the same implementation, just that I do it directly in the controllers where I use HttpContext instead of constructor injected one. 
Still my opt is null. What can be the problem? (I also use cookie scheme and it is registered in the middleware pipeline).

Comment: (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()).Ticket returns the same information with a single line. Works in all .net versions from core 2.0 to 7.

Comment: Could you update your answer for how to do this for the `Identity.ExternalC1` and `Identity.ExternalC2` cookies?

Comment: @idilov you are 100% right! However, `AuthenticateAsync` re-decrypts the cookie (just as my code) and reconstructs the principle, and this can affect performance (just as my code). So I updated the answer with another more elegant solution.

Comment: For multistage authentication: First a user logs in as a plain user with default cookie `scheme-plain` and if he wants to change his password he must log in again as a super user with cookie `scheme-super`.

From a certain endpoint, how can I retrieve all of his claims from both schemes? Can we use `HttpContext.Features...` to retrieve all claims he got from schemes `scheme-plain` and `scheme-super`?

Answer (score 12):

See below a helper method for .NET Core 2 to get claims from a cookie:

```cs
private IEnumerable<Claim> GetClaimFromCookie(HttpContext httpContext, string cookieName, string cookieSchema)
{
    // Get the encrypted cookie value
    var opt = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions>>();
    var cookie = opt.CurrentValue.CookieManager.GetRequestCookie(httpContext, cookieName);

    // Decrypt if found
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie))
    {
        var dataProtector = opt.CurrentValue.DataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", cookieSchema, "v2");
        
        var ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
        var ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookie);
        return ticket.Principal.Claims;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As was pointed by @Cirem, the dodgy way of creating a protector is exactly how Microsoft does it (see [their code here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions.cs)). Therefore, it may change in future versions.

Comment: It's apparently due to the cookie schema. What is the cookie schema anyway?

Comment: @liang, it's likely due to using a newer version of .NET Core. MS changed the code referred in my link in v2.2 and completely redesigned it in v3.

Answer (score 12):

Another variation for ASP.NET Core 2.2:

```cs
var cookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
var cookie = cookieManager.GetRequestCookie(HttpContext, ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application");

var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Identity.Application", "v2");

//Get the decrypted cookie as plain text
UTF8Encoding specialUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);
byte[] protectedBytes = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookie);
byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
string plainText = specialUtf8Encoding.GetString(plainBytes);


//Get teh decrypted cookies as a Authentication Ticket
TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
AuthenticationTicket ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookie);
```

Comment: Where does dataProtectionProvider come from?

Comment: @Pancake can be inject with DI in constructor, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider . You also need to add it to services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#persistkeystofilesystem

Answer (score 3):

I just got this working in Classic ASP.net (4.6.1). Note the following required installs:

- `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` (will come with a bunch of dependencies - note, I used verison 3.0.1 due to an exception, but that might not be necessary).
- `Microsfot.AspNetCore.DataProtection` (will come with a bunch of dependencies)
- Standard web stuff for the 4.6.1 framework

The following constants are defined by the framework:

- `PROVIDER_NAME = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware"`
- `SCHEME_NAME = "Identity.Application"`
- `COOKIE_NAME = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"` (can be customized)

The following constants are configuration-specific, but *must be the same between applications.*

- `APP_NAME = "Auth.Test.App"`
- `SHARED_KEY_DIR = "C:\\app-keyring"`

**The Process:**

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.0) was helpful in getting this set up on both sides, but particularly in properly configuring the .Net Core side. Thus, we shall leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Once you have these set up, on the **4.6.1 Decryption Side**, the following code will yield the `ClaimsIdentity` set in (for example) .Net Core 3.0:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
```

---

```
public static ClaimsIdentity GetClaimsIdentity(HttpContext context)
{
    //Get the encrypted cookie value
    var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[Constants.COOKIE_NAME];
    if (cookie == null) {
        return null;
    }
    var cookieValue = cookie.Value;

    //Get a data protector to use with either approach
    var keysDir = new DirectoryInfo(Constants.SHARED_KEY_DIR);
    if (!keysDir.Exists) { keysDir.Create(); }

    var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(keysDir,
        options => options.SetApplicationName(Constants.APP_NAME));
    var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(Constants.PROVIDER_NAME, Constants.SCHEME_NAME, "v2");

    //Get the decrypted cookie as a Authentication Ticket
    var shim = new DataProtectorShim(dataProtector);
    var ticketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(shim);
    var ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue);

    return ticket.Identity;
}
```