# How to gain access to Asp.Net Core encryption keys?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

A cookie provided by call:

```cs
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal);
```

is stored in encrypted state. How to get encryption key?

**IMPORTANT**: this question has grown from my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842511/how-to-manually-decrypt-an-asp-net-core-authentication-cookie/42857830?noredirect=1#comment72914288_42857830) about cookie decryption. Thanks to [Ron C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415614/ron-c) and his great answer.

Comment: Given the cookie is unencrypted automatically for you when it's sent back why do you believe you need access to the master keys?

Comment: @blowdart I tried to decrypt in manually (outside the application code). For example, by using the key and the encrypted value only. Actually that question is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gaining Access to the Keys**
By default the .net core framework goes to great lengths to keep the keys private and to help the developer to avoid any need for handling the keys.  This is good as it's quite difficult for developers to keep keys safe.

That said, with a change of configuration you can easily gain access to the keys.

Add the following line of code to the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup.cs` file. If you use use session, add it below the line for `AddSession`:

```cs
 services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keyDirPath));
```

and set `keyDirPath` to the operating system absolute path of the directory that you'd like the keys stored in.  The directory does not need to already exist as the system will create it on the fly.   In my case I set directory to a folder named Keys.  Here's what the directory looked like after running the code once, it contains one key file:

[image]

The contents of that key file are unencrypted and look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <key id="677f1115-644a-4b11-b045-0c3c51675ef1" version="1">
    <creationDate>2017-03-17T12:21:10.8909291Z</creationDate>
    <activationDate>2017-03-17T12:21:10.8419262Z</activationDate>
    <expirationDate>2017-06-15T12:21:10.8419262Z</expirationDate>
    <descriptor deserializerType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
      <descriptor>
        <encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC" />
        <validation algorithm="HMACSHA256" />
        <masterKey p4:requiresEncryption="true" xmlns:p4="http://schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection">
          <!-- Warning: the key below is in an unencrypted form. -->
          <value>BMJ6EY5MbcR0vaXhCbHggQcVsuYc6MnMtQpQm0qL647UBVx0YDbZufqQ+2/XuahFfIY2fJ6BIlOl+LYODnLbrA==</value>
        </masterKey>
      </descriptor>
    </descriptor>
  </key>
```

**WARNING:** You should never leave your keys laying around in a totally unprotected state in a folder named keys.  Doing so is **not** a security best practice.  But if you are trying to learn about the security system, it's a useful exercise.

You can learn more about the Data protection services here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview