# Decrypt Asp Net Core Identity cookie on PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I use ASP Net Core identity on a domain *.xyz.com, the user can log-in either on xyz.com or aaa.xyz.com, both are on ASP.Net Core and I can share the identity without issue.

I would like to set-up another subdomain like blog.xyz.com based on wordpress. I would like to auto-authenticate on this site, based on the cookie created by ASP. Is it possible to decrypt this cookie in PHP?

This is not about cross-domain issues, but about ASP Net Core identity Cookie decrypt in PHP.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript No, as written, I already have set up a cross-subdomain cookie which works well. The question is on the unencrypt of the ASP.NET Core identity cookie in PHP.

Comment: See [How to manually decrypt an ASP.NET Core Authentication cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842511/how-to-manually-decrypt-an-asp-net-core-authentication-cookie).

Comment: @MarkG Seen that thread, which is the most complete I found on the subject, but it is still .Net. My main issue is probably how to know if it is possible to translate  `var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));`
`var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).FullName, "MyCookie", "v2");`
to PHP...

Comment: You could look at using another encryption scheme using [TicketDataFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.ticketdataformat) instead of using DataProtectionProvider.