# Manually decrypt cookies set by asp.net core identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Based on what I learned from [How to manually decrypt and asp.net core auth cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842511/how-to-manually-decrypt-an-asp-net-core-authentication-cookie)
I tried to do the similar. The only difference is that the cookie is set by asp.net core identity. Here is the piece in SetUp.cs:

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>( options =>
        {
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"));
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And here is how I tried to setup decrypt in homeController.cs:

```
    var cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies;

    var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"));

    //Get a data protector to use with either approach
    var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector("Identity.Application", "Cookies", "v2");

    //Get the decrypted cookie as plain text
    UTF8Encoding specialUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);

    foreach (var cookie in cookies)
    {
        byte[] protectedBytes = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookie.Value);
        byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
        string plainText = specialUtf8Encoding.GetString(plainBytes);
    }
```

But I always get the following error:
The key {******-****} was not found in the key ring.

How to match up the key/dataProtectionProvider?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're trying to decrypt them? Also, are you sure your DataProtection keys are in sync? e.g. are both apps storing them in the same pace?

Comment: Just for fun and learning. I understand the cookie middleware decrypt them automatically. Both code blocks are in the same app and using the same folder/file.