# How can I control serialization of ASP.NET Core Cookie Authentication's claims, tickets, and properties?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, serialization

- I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC web-application that uses OIDC from a separate website.
- In `Startup.cs`, it has:

  ```
  services
      .AddAuthentication()
      .AddCookie( "Cookies", o => ... )
      .AddOpenIdConnect( "Oidc",  o => ... );
  ```
- The `access_token` from the ID Provider is about 800 bytes and the `id_token` is about 1500 bytes.
- When the `id_token` is retrieved, my code parses all of the `id_token` claims and converts them to strongly-typed C# object properties and then generates a `List<Claim>` based on these properties. This `List<Claim>` is then passed into ASP.NET Core's `SignInAsync` method.
- However, the ASP.NET Core cookie that is issued is often over 7,000 bytes (!!) and it's so big that it's spread out over 2 or 3 cookies (using ASP.NET Core's Chunked Cookies feature). This causes a problem because Chrome sometimes rejects cookies that exceed 4096 bytes.
- I used this trick ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/55729188/159145 ) to convert the chunked cookies into a single binary which I used a hex-editor to inspect and I saw how the space was being used:

  - Each of the `Claim` items from my `List<Claim>` is serialized (as expected), but each `Claim`'s `ClaimValueType` is also serialized with the full issuer URI (23 bytes) and  full XML data-type URI, e.g. `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"` (40 bytes) (I note that ASP.NET Core seems to omit the full XML data-type URI if it's `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"` - it's unfortunate because the reason I used `integer` in the first place was to save the space from string encoding and quotes.

    - Combined, these all use about 1,900 bytes of the 7,000 byte cookie.
  - Next, the various OIDC values are stored, such as the `AuthScheme.oidc\r.sessionState` and `.Token.access_token”`. I note that these values are Base64-encoded already and are then doubly encoded by ASP.NET Core. (So if ASP.NET Core was smarter it would un-encode any Base64 values and represent them as their original binary form, then pass that into the data-protection (encryption) and then run the outer-Base64 - but I digress.
  - After that, the `.Token.id_token` is redundantly stored. This is redundant because all of the `id_token`'s claims have been parsed out into the `ClaimsIdentity` - but there's no option in `AddOpenIdConnect` to only save `access_token` into the user's cookie and to drop the `id_token`.

    - Actually, the `id_token` must be saved because it's needed to use the OIDC sign-out `hint` feature (the original `id_token` string must be provided back to the IP, verbatim).

I see a few possibilities for optimizing this - but very little documentation anywhere online about how to accomplish it.

- Can I prevent any (or most) of the `Claim` values being serialized and instead have ASP.NET Core materialize the `Claim` objects by re-parsing the `id_token`?
- I can have ASP.NET Core use the User Info Endpoint for Claims instead of using `id_token`, but how do I do that while still ensuring I get all of the OpenID Identity Resources I need?
- How can I ensure each `Claim` value is serialized efficiently?
- How can I prevent double-Base64-encoding of things like the `access_token` and `id_token` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 years later someone upvoted my question-posting which prompted me to post my code from my PR to the ASP.NET Core team from June 2019 which [was rejected because applying compression *before* encrypting user-provided input opens you up to the CRIME and BREACH vulnerabilities](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10951) - it might take a while to get your head over it, but it makes sense and I agree with @Blowdart's decision to reject it as *general purpose code*.

...however I understand that it's still okay to use *if* there's no untrusted/unverified-user-provided secrets in the cookie - so if all you're storing is some non-secret or fixed-sized (e.g. `Int32`) values that remote-users have no control over then it isn't really vulnerable to CRIME/BREACH:

Enjoy: https://github.com/Jehoel/aspnetcore-auth-cookie-optimizations