# How .NET framework sets the Cookie value when use cookies authentication and session store

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
    {
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        CookieName = "MySessionCookie",
        SessionStore = dbSessionStore
    });
    //...
}
```

Once user logged in, `"MySessionCookie"` is getting setup and can see in Browser Developer options. Kind of encrypted value. Tried to do `Base64String` conversion but throwing exception.

How Cookie value will be assigned when we use cookie authentication? Thanks
Is it a Base64String or some encryption used by .NET Framework?

Comment: reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842511/how-to-manually-decrypt-an-asp-net-core-authentication-cookie